# Hazelcast: Multiple Hazelcast Nodes are created in response to a single newHazelcastInstance call

Tags: hazelcast

I have a small hazelcast cluster which is under a medium sized and constant load. When I scale the cluster by adding a new server I get an interesting and unexplained result. As part of the creation of a new server I call Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(hzConfig);. This call normally creates a single hazelcast node in the cluster (as verified using their management console). In some of my test cases, this call is creating many hazelcast nodes in the cluster (testing has shown as many as 7 new nodes being created). Has anyone else seen this behavior? Is there a way to control this? Why is this happening? Can the number of nodes will be spawned be predicted?

Answer (score 0):

Does the logging of members by the members themselves show a different result, because what you see there is the truth.

It could be that there is a bug in the management center.

So can you post the logging of the members?

It should look something like this:

```
Members [2] {
    Member [192.168.1.104]:5701 this
    Member [192.168.1.104]:5702
}
```